# Xamarin, Prism and IOS Webview Exception

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, prism

It looks like this is something to do with Prism. We are using Xamarin 4.8 and Prism and in IOS and all I have done is dropped a

```
<webview></webview>
```

'
and I get this exception.

I thought make I needed to set the source but
that didn't change matters. I got to be missing something simple.

Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: *** -[NSCoder decodeObjectOfClasses:forKey:]: This method is only implemented for coders which allowKeyedCoding.
Native stack trace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011ea2aaf6 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011f2b8e78 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   Foundation                          0x0000000118c74b8a -[NSCoder decodeObjectOfClasses:forKey:error:] + 0
3   WebKit                              0x0000000117ca3bcb -[WKWebViewConfiguration initWithCoder:] + 87
4   S3.Core.Mobile.iOS                  0x000000010cb32359 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217
5   ???                                 0x000000015c0b2a00 0x0 + 5839202816

[image: WebView2]

Comment: Hi, if you update the version of Xamarin Forms to the latest version, whether it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We are using Xamarin 4.8 and Prism

I found that you are using the old version of Xamarin Forms, then you could upadte the version of Xamarin Forms to the latest version (`5.0.0.1931`) to check whether it works.